# JPA without Java EE, Is it possible?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

Is it possible develop Java applications using JPA without Java EE?
So, if it is possible, may I configure my java application with Tomcat?

Comment: "Without Java EE" doesn't make sense. Java EE is an umbrella spec, JPA is one of its parts. So in a way if you're using JPA you're using some Java EE, just like if you're using Tomcat (i.e. servlets) you're using another bit of Java EE. Its consistent technologies are mostly orthogonal and can be made to run without one another - you just need to bootstrap the JPA implementation yourself instead of having the container do it for you. (The JPA implementation's docs will tell you how.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "without Java EE" means to you.  Are you saying you don't want to use a Java EE container like JBOSS, WebLogic, WebSphere?

You can certainly use Tomcat or Jetty.  You need JPA JARs, of course.

You can use [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) to help you.  It can deploy nicely on Tomcat.

The beauty of Spring is that you can use just what you need and leave the rest.

Comment: Yes, I am referring that I do not want to use a Java EE container like JBOSS, WebLogic, WebSphere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JPA with Spring in a servlet container like Jetty or Tomcat, makes absolutely no difference. JPA in an unmanaged environment is also possible, you just need to list all entities in your `persistence.xml` and handle transactions yourself.